# Image not visible while working on Login form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a login section which looks like this - https://www.codehim.com/demo/login-page-in-html-with-css-code/

On left hand side I have an image and on right hand side, I have login form -

This is what I have done -

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

On login__left I have added a image through CSS but it is not visible.

Can you help me.

Comment: when you give width and height by percentages be sure that parent and his parent have sizes to

Comment: Are you sure about the addressing? Put the image address in your browser's URL and see if its correct

Answer (score 0):

You'r `login__left` doesn't have any height. check if you set your height in `px`

Comment: Yes I tried height as 100vh and it worked.

Comment: But somehow I am seeing the scrollbar now although I have mentioned overflow: hidden

Comment: So the problem is solved, when you put any content in you'r div the image will be displayed